# jQuery fadeIn and than move to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make function, which fade in `div` on click and than it should move to that `div`. But it doesn't work, with first click `div` appears and I have to click one more time to move there.
Could someone help me out please?
https://jsfiddle.net/qzdxf478/

```
<a href="#princip-detail" class="showDetail">Continue</a>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.showDetail').click(function() {
                    $('#princip-detail').fadeIn();
                    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                        var target = $(this.hash);
                        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                        if (target.length) {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: target.offset().top
                            }, 1000);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Create a JsFiddle pls we lack a part of the code to help you :/

Comment: @Baldráni updated, link is in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the default action of the anchor you click using `e.preventDefault();`. Don't forget to include the jQuery library. Run the snippet below to see it in action:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showDetail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#princip-detail').fadeIn();
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#principy {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url('main-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 20;
}

#princip-detail {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #f00 url("page-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="principy">
  <div class="princip-topleft">
    <h2><a href="#princip-detail" class="showDetail">Continue</a></h2>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="princip-detail">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="principy">
  <div class="princip-topleft">
    <h2><a href="#princip-detail" class="showDetail">Continue</a></h2></div>

</div>

<div id="princip-detail">
  133131321212121323232323
</div>

#principy {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url('main-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 20;
}

#princip-detail {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url("page-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

   $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.showDetail').click(function() {
                var curLink = this.hash;
                $(curLink).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                  var offset = $(curLink).offset().top;
                  $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: offset
                  }, 1000);

                });
              });
            });
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/5xj5Lg53/